# Facing issue with MS Graph send email through delegated permission and service account

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

```
  IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create("ClientId")
        .WithTenantId("TenantId")
        .Build();
  UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication);
  GraphServiceClient _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

await _graphClient.Me
      .SendMail(message, true)
       .Request().WithUsernamePassword("ServiceAccountUser", "ServiceAccountUserPassword")
      .PostAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Added permission:

[image]

Graph SDK: 4

**Error:
The given key 'Microsoft.Graph.AuthenticationHandlerOption' was not present in the dictionary.**

Can someone please  help me to understnad this issue?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp#access-token-provider

Comment: Found sample code using sendmail : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-1-send-a-new-email-using-json-format

Comment: @jdweng I want to use WithUsernamePassword so I can send email thorough service account with delegated permission.

Comment: it's not recommended to use [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth-ropc)(use username and password), but if you want to use it, then here's [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp#usernamepassword-provider). By the way, ROPC flow only supports work/school accounts. And this might help as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/75318761/14574199

Comment: You can't if the server doesn't expect username/password.  Most system will not use Username/Password because the password is not encrypted.  You may be able to use Credentials with Username/Password if server allows for it.  Most systems moved from Windows Credentials to OAUTH2 because OAUTH2 works with Windows, Linux, and MAC.